# Lost OS(windows 10) and partitions(which had all my files) while installing ubuntu 14.10

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

Lost OS(windows 10) and partitions(which had all my files) while installing ubuntu 14.10(which now, I upgraded to 15.04 since testdisk did not work in 14.10). I would like to know if there is any chance to recover my lost files from the partitions which I had before. Now all the partitions are combined to one 991 GB partition hard disk with just ubuntu 15.04 in it. I am new user of Ubuntu. Please help me. Thank you. Tried Testdisk did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Ubuntu, you have the option to erase the whole disk and install Ubuntu, or you could make the partition table yourself. Since you are a beginner Linux user, you probally erased the whole disk.

To answer your question about retrieving files from your previous OS. Yes, it is possible to extract files. (But you can't restore your Windows OS.) There are numerous programs on the internet to retrieve deleted files. When you delete a file, it isn't entirely lost. It still resides on your hard disk. What you should do is stop using the hard drive and plug it as a second hard drive in another PC. Then download software to try to retrieve those files. (Search google "retrieve deleted files")

Good luck!